# SUM of cells based on the value of cells on the right and above

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, filter, sum, array-formulas

[image: Example of my working sheet]

Y3 (Total forecast) = Sum of all actuals for the months that have actuals + Sum of all forecast for the remaining months where there are no actuals yet.

Currently, I am using this formula: Y3

```
=SUMIF(A2:H2, Z2, A3:H3)+SUMIF(I2:X2, Y2, I3:X3)
```

It works. But I have to manually update the formula every month when actual costs are in. So I want to set up a formula that dynamically changes the sum when the cell refers to "Actual" is not empty.

I've tried SUM with OFFSET, INDIRECT and ADDRESS. Nothing works for me so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use in **Y3** cell:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(FILTER(A3:X3, A2:X2="actual"),
 INDIRECT(ADDRESS(3, MIN(IF(A3:X3="", COLUMN(A:X)-1, )))&":X3")))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thanks @player0, I think your formula it is getting very close to the outcomes that I want. It sums up the forescast of the months that have actuals whereas I only want the actuals in the total sum only.

Comment: can you share a copy of jour sheet with example of desired output?

Comment: Probably I did something wrong when I plugged your formula in the real spreadsheet. I tested your formula again, using the test figures. It worked like a charm.  Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Use this formula:

```
=IFERROR(SUM(FILTER(A3:X3,{B3:X3,""}<>"",A2:X2=Y2)),0)
```

and

```
=IFERROR(SUM(FILTER(A3:X3,A3:X3<>"",A2:X2=Z2)),0)
```

Update:

```
=arrayformula(sum(if(A2:X2="Actual",A3:X3,0)+
                  if(A2:X2="Forecast",if({B3:X3,""}="",A3:X3,0),0)))
```

This can be change with sumif, but I have not tested it

Another 1:

```
=arrayformula(sum(A3:X3-if(A2:X2="Forecast",if({B3:X3,""}<>"",A3:X3,0),0)))
```

Another 2:

```
=arrayformula(sum(if (A2:X2="forecast",if({B3:X3,0}="",A3:X3,{B3:X3,0}),0)))
```

Comment: Thanks @user11982798, your formula yielded 0 in the output. I am not sure why.